# Updating python version 3.9.2 to 3.9.10

Tags: python-3.x, updating, raspberry-pi4

I have "bog standard" python3.9.2 installed on my rasperry pi.  I would like to upgrade/update to python3.9.10 (not python 3.10).  Presumably very simple as no one seems to have asked this ever anywhere, but how?

Comment: do you use `raspbian` os?

Comment: Lone I have a pi 4 which, I understand, uses what is now called the raspberry pi os